# How to update a boolean value based on the value in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular7

I have an array of objects as below, and only one object has userInfo value as "true" and I want to update another boolean value (globally declared) to true only for the object which has userInfo element.
How to get this, please help.

```
dataList = [
    0: {name: "User 1", value: "value 1"}  
    1: {name: "User 2", value: "value 2"}
    2: {name: "User 3", value: "value 3"}  
    3: {name: "User 4", value: "value 4"}
    4: {name: "User 5", value: "value 5", userInfo: true}
]
```

Comment: What is your wanted result? And what have you tried yet?

Comment: I tried this, but it is effecting all the objects in the array......this.dataList.forEach(element => {
        if(element.userInfo) {
          this.setGlobal = true;
        }
      });

Comment: Where do you have the array of object (`dataList`)? And where is the global boolean variable you want to update? Also when do you want this to be triggered?

Comment: Use `some`: `this.setGlobal = dataList.some(({userInfo})=>userInfo)`

Comment: @user10742586 I'm assuming if one of `userInfo` is `true` then this `setGlobal` should be set to `true` or `false` vice versa

Comment: @gorak correct.

Comment: @user10742586 you need to provide more context to the question, otherwise you might describing the bug with your assumption and thus the answers wont help you. Please check my comment above again.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and update the global value accordingly:

`this.setGlobal = dataList.some(({userInfo})=>userInfo)`

`setGlobal` will be set to `true` if one of `userInfo` is `true` otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your array has a syntax problem.
I don't know exactly what you want to do, but I'm guessing something like this can help:

```js
// Declared boolean
let myBool = false

// Array with correct syntax
const dataList = [
    {name: "User 1", value: "value 1"},
    {name: "User 2", value: "value 2"},
    {name: "User 3", value: "value 3"},  
    {name: "User 4", value: "value 4"},
    {name: "User 5", value: "value 5", userInfo: true}
]
// Filter the array item you want
const userToUpdate = dataList.filter(user => user.userInfo === true)[0]
// Update your prvious boolean
myBool = userToUpdate.userInfo
console.log(myBool)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let globalBool = false;
const dataList = [
    {name: "User 1", value: "value 1"},
    {name: "User 2", value: "value 2"},
    {name: "User 3", value: "value 3"}, 
    {name: "User 4", value: "value 4"},
    {name: "User 5", value: "value 5", userInfo: true}
];

function setGlobalVariable(){
    globalBool = dataList.some(data => data.userInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.entries to check the keyName and value and then set the global boolean value

```
dataList.forEach(eachRowItem => {
  const entries = Object.entries(eachRowItem);
  
  entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
   if (key === 'userInfo') {
     this.globalBool = value;
   }
  })
})
```